# Custom menu for mobile

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a navigation like so:

```
<nav id="menu">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="/preview/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">   <a href="/preview/#about-us" class="dropdown-toggle scroll" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">About Us <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

            <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="history.php">History</a></li>
                <li><a href="our-pledge.php">Our Pledge</a></li>
                <li><a href="giving-back.php">Giving Back</a></li>
                <li><a href="awards.php">Awards</a></li>
                <li><a href="in-the-press.php">In The Press</a></li>
                <li><a href="design-centre.php?action=video-testimonials">Video Tertimonials</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="/preview/#communities">Communities</a></li>
        <li><a href="/preview/#pronto">Pronto</a></li>
        <li><a href="/preview/#gallery">Gallery</a></li>
        <li><a href="/preview/#virtual-tours">Virtual Tours</a></li>
        <li class="dropdown">   <a href="/preview/#design-centre" class="dropdown-toggle scroll" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Design Centre <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

            <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="design-centre.php?action=video-testimonials">Video Tertimonials</a></li>
                <li><a href="design-centre.php?action=meet-the-team">Meet The Team</a></li>
                <li><a href="design-centre.php?action=faq">FAQ</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="dropdown">   <a href="/preview/#customer-care" class="dropdown-toggle scroll" data-toggle="dropdown" data-hover="dropdown">Customer Care <i class="fa fa-angle-down"></i></a>

            <ul class="menulist dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="warranty-information.php">Warranty Information</a></li>
                <li><a href="home-maintenance.php">Home Maintenance Tips</a></li>
                <li><a href="emergencies.php">Emergencies</a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
    </ul>
</nav><!--menu-->
```

and for mobile, I added this item:

```
<button class="navbar-toggle button-white menu" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".navbar-collapse"> 
    <i class="fa fa-bars"></i>
</button>
```

Currently, if its mobile, the menu will not appear, but the button will. When it is mobile, I am looking for the user to click the buttton and a dropdown appears with the menu options. My question is what would be the best way to do this?

I have bootstrap.js installed and bootstrap-hover-dropdown.min.js also

Comment: Isn't boostrap-hover included in bootstrap.js? All of what you describe is clearly demonstrated in the docs. What's not working, exactly?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a simple, and very good solution to do this [HERE](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/codelab.php?topic=bootstrap&file=dropdowns-within-navbar), with [THIS](http://www.tutorialrepublic.com/twitter-bootstrap-tutorial/bootstrap-dropdowns.php) detailed explanation of different menu options. 
If you want to see how it will react in a mobile environment, just re-size the browser window.

The markup looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Example of Bootstrap 3 Dropdowns within a Navbar</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/css/bootstrap-theme.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.2/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<style type="text/css">
    .bs-example{
        margin: 20px;
    }
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="bs-example">
    <nav id="myNavbar" class="navbar navbar-default" role="navigation">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
                <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                    <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">Brand</a>
            </div>
            <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
            <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
                    <li><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a href="#">Profile</a></li>
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Messages <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Inbox</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Drafts</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Sent Items</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Trash</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                    <li class="dropdown">
                        <a href="#" data-toggle="dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle">Admin <b class="caret"></b></a>
                        <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                            <li><a href="#">Action</a></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Another action</a></li>
                            <li class="divider"></li>
                            <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
        </div>
    </nav>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```